# plane perpendicular to the straight line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

I have this problem to find the equation of the plane perpendicular to the straight line joining the points $(1, 3, 5)$ and $(4, 3 ,2)$ at its middle points.  How would you solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You mean the plane intersects the segment from $(1,3,5)$ to $(4,3,2)$ at its midpoint?  Do you know the coordinates of the midpoint?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner well the coordinate of the midpoint can be found from the coordinates of the given points.

Comment: So what are they?  And do you know the direction vector of the line, which is perpendicular to the plane?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner https://imgur.com/a/tfMcuGH, notice that the normal(in blue) is the cross product of the vectors that meet at the midpoint
and the midpoint is simply the average of each coordinate between both points

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be a straight line joining $(1,3,5)$ and $(4,3,2)$?  It doesn't appear straight in your picture

Comment: @J.W.Tanner you can draw that line, the question is asking for the line perpindicular to the plane that passes through the midpoint
which is just the normal that defines the plane

Comment: In other words, don't both of the vectors from the points to the midpoint have the same direction (as the line), so their cross product is $\vec0$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner right

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I have some other problems, are you here for a bit? So I can update the question?

Comment: If you have other questions, you should post them separately

Comment: sure, it s just I don't know if I get an answer or not, sometimes I don't, so I said since you re available, why not post them here? Is it Ok?

Answer (score 1):

Any plane can be expressed uniquely by a normal direction, and a point through which it passes. You have been given both these things, only you need to extract them.

The normal direction $\hat{n} = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$

The point through which it passes $\vec{O} = \left(\frac{5}{2}, 3, \frac{7}{2}\right)$

Now assume the plane has the equation

$$ax + by + cz = d$$

Here, the tuple $(a,b,c)$ correspond to the plane normal, and will be parallel to it, and $d$ is used to ensure it passes through $\vec{O}$

$$\pi: x - z = -1$$

Comment: Isn't $\vec O$ supposed to be in $\pi$?

Comment: Whoops, calculation mistake. Fixed it

Comment: that's right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The formula for it is: $(X-X_0)\cdot \vec{n}=0$ whereas $X = (x,y,z), X_0 = \left(\frac{1+4}{2}, \frac{3+3}{2}, \frac{2+5}{2}\right)=\left(\frac{5}{2}, 3, \frac{7}{2}\right)$ , and $\vec{n}= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3^2+0^2+(-3)^2}}\left(4-1,3-3,2-5\right)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\left(3,0,-3\right)=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 0,\dfrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$. Can you complete the equation?

Comment: Hi can you please help on this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751812/finding-the-equation-of-an-hyperbola-if-the-distance-between-its-directrices-is

Answer (score 0):

The line has direction vector $(4-1,3-3,2-5)=(3,0,-3)$.

The midpoint is $\dfrac{(1,3,5)+(4,3,2)}2=(2.5,3,3.5)$.

Therefore, the equation of the plane is $3x+0y+-3z=3(2.5)-3(3.5)$;

i.e., $3x-3z=-3 $, or $x-z=-1$.

Comment: Hi please can you help on this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751812/finding-the-equation-of-an-hyperbola-if-the-distance-between-its-directrices-is