# Finding the equation of an hyperbola if the distance between its directrices is $\frac83$ and its eccentricity is $\frac32$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have this problem:

> Find the canonical equation of an hyperbola if the distance between the directrices is $\frac{8}{3}$ and the eccentricity $e=\frac{3}{2}$.

How would you solve it?

**This is my try:**

The canonical equation of a hyperbola takes the form $x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 = 1$, and the foci are at a distance $c > a$ from the origin, and our directrices are located at $a^2/c$, where eccentricity is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}/a$. If $e = 3/2$, then

\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a} = \frac32 
&\implies \frac32 a = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \\[4pt]
&\implies \frac94 a^2 = a^2 + b^2 \\[4pt]
&\implies a^2\left(\frac94 - 1\right) = b^2 && (c^2 = a^2 + b^2)
\end{align}

so
\begin{align}
a^2 + a^2\left(\frac94-1\right) = c^2 
&\implies c^2 = a^2\left(1 + \frac94 - 1\right) \\[4pt]
&\implies c^2 = \frac94 a^2 \\[4pt]
&\implies c = \frac32 a
\end{align}
so our directrix is located at

$$\frac{a^2}{c} = \frac{a^2}{a\cdot 3/2} = \frac{a}{3/2} = \frac{2}{3}\cdot a,$$
but the distance between directrices is $8/3$, so it's double the distance from the origin, so essentially,
$$ \frac{8}{3} = 2x = 2\cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot a
\implies \frac{8}{3} = \frac{4}{3} \cdot a
\implies a = 2. $$
And since

$$ c^2 - a^2
= b^2
= \frac{9}{4} \cdot 4^2 - 4^2
= 16 \left( \frac{9}{4} - 1\right)
= 4 \cdot 9 - 16
= 36-16
=20. $$

In total, we have
$$a^2 = 4, \qquad\text{and}\qquad b^2 = 20,$$
which results in the canonical form
$$\frac{x^2}{4} -\frac{y^2}{20} = 1.$$

Also, how would you find the eccentricity of an ellipse if the sides of the square inscribed in it pass through the foci of the ellipse?

**My try:**

Let’s imagine a generic ellipse, and the square inside has its sides located at $-x$ and $x$, making the side of the square $2x$, and we know that the foci occur at
$$ x = \frac{a^2}{c}
\quad\text{so}\quad
2x = \frac{2a^2}{c},
\qquad\text{(since $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$)},$$
and eccentricity is
$$ \frac{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{a} = \frac{c}{a}, $$
so if $ e = c/a $ and
$$ 2x = \frac{2a^2}{c} = 2a \cdot \frac{a}{c} = 2a\cdot \frac{1}{e} = \frac{2a}{2}
\implies x = \frac{a}{2}
\implies e = \frac{a}{x}
$$
and $x$ would be half the side of the square in this case.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It would help to add what you've tried so far / how far you've gotten. Not often will people receive an answer with no work done prior.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... You should ask the ellipse question separately. ... In any case, questions should include something of what you know about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already  know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. Isolated problem statements tend to give the wrong impression in this regard.)

Comment: I am just doing some game development and I have to solve these problems, it will occur many times, so I want to learn about.

Comment: So do you have any knowledge of coordinate geometry or conic sections?

Comment: yes, I think I can understand the answer

Comment: You can easily find the equation of the hyperbola imposing $d(P,F)=\epsilon d(P,r)$, where $P$ is a general point $(x,y)$. Then, using orthogonal invariants you reduce your equation to its canonical form.

Comment: @psidaga can you please outline your answer below?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I tried to formulate my problem so It can be understood by people here.

Comment: Pure problem statement are considered off-topic here and may be flagged for closure. Can you add more information of the context like where did you encountered this question or what more do you know about the mathematical terms you used. It will be helpful for other users also to directly address the problem.

Comment: Pls draw the hyperbola along with its directrices. Given you know the eccentricity and distance between directrices, you can easily find the length of transverse and conjugate axes. That will give you the equation.

Comment: @MathLover I updated with my try, correct?

Comment: @Blue I did my try, correct?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan my try correct?

Comment: @Graviton please review my try?

Comment: Thanks for adding your attempt, and please wait for your question to be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

In the hyperbola exercise, you double-squared the $a$ in your $c^2-a^2 = \cdots = 20$ calculation, effectively multiplying everything by an extra factor of $4$. You should get $9-4=5$, instead.

---

Here's a clearer path to the solution:

If the hyperbola's transverse semi-axis is $a$, its center-to-focus distance is $c$, and its eccentricity is $e$, then the center-to-directrix distance (call it $d$) is indeed given by $d=a^2/c$, so that (since $e=c/a$) we can write $a = de$.

Since the distance between the directrices is $8/3$, we have $d=4/3$; given the eccentricity $3/2$, we have
$$a = de=\frac43\cdot\frac32=2 \tag{1}$$
Then,
$$c=ae = 2\cdot\frac32=3 \tag{2}$$
and then
$$b^2=c^2-a^2=9-4=5\tag{3}$$
so that, for an origin-centered hyperbola with a horizontal transverse axis, the equation is
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 \quad\to\quad \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{y^2}{5}=1 \tag{$\star$}$$

---

(I think the ellipse question should be posted separately, so I won't address it here.)